# ReactJS typescript deployment with PHP Laravel goes white screen with no errors?

Tags: reactjs

I have a working reactjs project that I created with `create-react-app --typescript` option.

when running `npm run start` my app works completely fine.

When doing `npm run-script build` my app builds fine aswell with a few in-component warnings that are not really relevant because I get them on development too.

After that I do `serve -s build` to serve the built files to test if it works, and it works completely fine!

After moving my `build` files to the public directory of laravel, with the correct paths, and going to `localhost:8000/index.html` which looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.797c8761.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
        ! function(l) {
            function e(e) {
                for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], f = 0, i = []; f < n.length; f++) t = n[f], p[t] && i.push(p[t][0]), p[t] = 0;
                for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]);
                for (s && s(e); i.length;) i.shift()();
                return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a()
            }

            function a() {
                for (var e, r = 0; r < c.length; r++) {
                    for (var t = c[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) {
                        var u = t[o];
                        0 !== p[u] && (n = !1)
                    }
                    n && (c.splice(r--, 1), e = f(f.s = t[0]))
                }
                return e
            }
            var t = {},
                p = {
                    1: 0
                },
                c = [];

            function f(e) {
                if (t[e]) return t[e].exports;
                var r = t[e] = {
                    i: e,
                    l: !1,
                    exports: {}
                };
                return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f), r.l = !0, r.exports
            }
            f.m = l, f.c = t, f.d = function(e, r, t) {
                f.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
                    enumerable: !0,
                    get: t
                })
            }, f.r = function(e) {
                "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                    value: "Module"
                }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                    value: !0
                })
            }, f.t = function(r, e) {
                if (1 & e && (r = f(r)), 8 & e) return r;
                if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r;
                var t = Object.create(null);
                if (f.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
                        enumerable: !0,
                        value: r
                    }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r)
                    for (var n in r) f.d(t, n, function(e) {
                        return r[e]
                    }.bind(null, n));
                return t
            }, f.n = function(e) {
                var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                    return e.default
                } : function() {
                    return e
                };
                return f.d(r, "a", r), r
            }, f.o = function(e, r) {
                return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
            }, f.p = "/";
            var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [],
                n = r.push.bind(r);
            r.push = e, r = r.slice();
            for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) e(r[o]);
            var s = n;
            a()
        }([])
    </script>
    <script src="/static/js/2.88b8a249.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.d118929d.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

My page responds 200 with a blank white screen, and the console outputs no errors:

[image: img]

When I go to `view-page-sources` and click on any of the js files links, the link loads just fine!

What could be the problem? Why does it not work on laravel via public folder, but does work when i do `serve -s build`?

Comment: Any console error or warning?

Comment: @Emanuele Nope, as described in the question in the image, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because my router sees the route as `index.html` because that's how I access the react app in the URL.

To solve that, I copied and placed the contents of `index.html` to `welcome.blade.php` and rendered it with `/` route listener `view('welcome')` on `/`.